# Source bashrc in WSL in a non-interactive, non-login shell

Tags: keychain, wsl-2, ssh-agent

I am working on a project, and I have a problem with WSL and `bashrc`. To elaborate a little bit, I have `keychain` and I want to run a `keychain` command every time I use a WSL command.

So I added that command in my `~./bashrc`.

If from my Windows Terminal I use `wsl bash -ic "command"`, my command inside `~/.bashrc` runs.

My problem now is that I have another program that runs WSL without the `bash -ic` params, and I can't change that.

Do you know how I can address this problem or find a workaround?

Basically, I want it so that every time I use WSL from my Windows Terminal, it runs the `keychain` command first.

For example, let's say that I want to run `wsl git push`.  I want my `keychain` command to execute before the `git push` runs.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, you are trying to make sure that a `keychain` command runs before each command that requires it?  I'm assuming you are referring to  [`keychain`](https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain), right?  Are you just trying to make sure that a key is added to `ssh-agent` before the `git` commands run?  Does the key require a password to be entered?  Do you really need the `keychain` command to run *every time* before another command, or do you just need to make sure that the `git` command (for example) can access the key on the keychain?

Comment: Oh, and as I was editing your question, I realized you mention running from the "window terminal" (which I assume means "Windows Terminal"). But the terminal doesn't matter - What _shell_ are you running in the terminal? PowerShell? CMD? (Please say PowerShell ;-)

Comment: You are correct.I am developing a plugin for intellij more specific a ui for radicle.So radicle is only for linux right now and i installed it successfully in my ubuntu (wsl2).The problem is that when i run my plugin from intellijj i suspect that intellij run wsl git push command because my git path is /wsl/ubuntu... and i am getting an error ssh-agent is not running.If i open a new terminal my ssh agent is running because i put it in bashrc.So the problem is that wsl without this parameters bash -ic doesnt run bashrc first.

Comment: yes i want git to access the key on keychain

Comment: Hmm - This is going to be tough.  Are you developing this plugin so that others will be able to use it easily?  If so, then at the moment, you would expect them to have `keychain` in their startup as well, right?  Or is the plugin for your use only?  I ask because there are ways to solve it for *you* via configuration that may not be acceptable for general-use.

Comment: yy i expected them to use keychain , this is a plugin for general use..i have instructions for this but I cant bypass this problem. If you have something in mind to help me... Right now radicle is only for linux dist and i can use it via windows only with wsl but i cannot find a solutution for this right now.If somehow i can tell to wsl to load bashrc.For linux my plugin runs perfectly btw

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds how can i do that via configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've noodled on this on-and-off for several days to see if I could come up with a better solution.  Nothing I can think of is *optimal*, but I think I ended up pretty close.

To restate/frame the problem:

- You need a WSL distribution to run a certain *interactive* command (`keychain`) that loads its environment variables into the user's WSL/Bash session.  This needs to happen to load the key into `ssh-agent` so that `wsl git` commands in IntelliJ will work with your plugin.
- `keychain` will ask for a password for the key to be loaded if one is required.
- `keychain` will output the environment variables needed for `ssh-agent` in a format that can be evaluated/sourced back into the Bash session.

  <sub>(Side-note:  It's really lucky that I've been using `keychain` for a couple of decades now, so I know its process flow fairly well).</sub>
- When run with `wsl git ...`, WSL launches the shell (Bash) as a non-interactive, non-login shell, so `~/.bashrc` is not processed.  Because of this, even if the key had been previously loaded into `ssh-agent` (by `keychain`), the Bash session does not have the proper `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`.

As a result of this, the `git` commands in your plugin are likely to fail for the user, since they require key-based authentication.

I think the above at least captures the spirit of the problem you are trying to solve.

Unfortunately, there's just no method that I'm aware of to force Bash to load its startup files when it is a non-interactive, non-login shell other than things that would modify the WSL command-line.

##### Proposed workaround - `$WSLENV` chain-loading IntelliJ

This is "pretty close" to optimal, I believe.  Your users would need to launch IntelliJ *through* WSL and use the [`$WSLENV`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) feature to pass through the correct environment variables.  This could be done interactively or through `~/.bashrc`.

Add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
eval $(keychain --eval ~/.ssh/<keyfile>)
export WSLENV=$WSLENV:SSH_AGENT_PID:SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

With this in place, you should be able to run:

```
wsl -e bash -lic /path/to/intellij.exe
```

It will ask for the key password and (as normal) add the `SSH_AGENT_PID`/`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variables to the shell session.  It will *also* add those variable *names* to $WSLENV, so that they are passed to any *Windows* process launched from inside WSL.

When the IntelliJ Windows executable is launched this way, the three variables will also be available in its environment:

- `WSLENV`
- `SSH_AGENT_PID`
- `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

And when IntelliJ then runs `wsl git ...`, those three variables will *also* be passed back *into* WSL, so that `git` will be able to access the key from `ssh-agent`.

While I don't have IntelliJ, I've tested this successfully using:

```
wsl -e bash -lic pwsh.exe # or powershell.exe
```

Then, from PowerShell:

```
> $env:WSLENV
WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID:SSH_AGENT_PID:SSH_AUTH_SOCK

> $env:SSH_AGENT_PID
45

> $env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXTWbsTa/agent.44

> cd some-dir
> wsl git clone "git@github.com:NotTheDr01ds/<private_repo>"
```

It worked as expected.

##### Other options

This is actually a bit easier if your users are using (or open to using) some shells other than Bash:

- The Fish shell startup files that are sourced even for non-login, non-interactive shells *plus* it supports "universal variables" that allow the `SSH_A*` variables to automagically be made available to *all* running (and future) Fish instances.
- Zsh has a startup file (`~/.zshenv`) that is sourced for non-login, non-interactive shells.  It's a little more complicated than Fish, but it's workable.

I actually started with these as proposed solutions before I found that `$WSLENV` was a workable solution (that didn't require a shell change).  However, if you want to see my write-up on how to do this in Zsh or Fish, just look at the edit history for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 you can run script when wsl is starting, create or edit (as sudo) `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

```
[boot]
command="command to run"
```

Add there the commands you want.

Comment: Can i use this with windows 10 ? or do you have a workaround.I tried with windows 10 but it doesnt work

Comment: @stelios It does not work with Windows 10, but further, the `/etc/wsl.conf` boot.command doesn't work with anything that needs user interaction.  I'm assuming you are entering a password into `keychain` at boot to add a key to the agent.  If so, you wouldn't be able to use `boot.command` anyway.

Comment: This is exactly what i do...