# Can I use zsh as the default non-interactive shell for WSL2 Ubuntu?

Tags: zsh, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide, wsl-2

I am trying to use Run/Debug Configurations on WebStorm, however it doesn't seem to source .zshrc and produces errors about not finding commands and environment variables. (An example of this would be `yarn tauri dev` when using Tauri)

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL and the project I opened in WebStorm resides under the $HOME directory. WebStorm is installed in Windows.

For the interactive shell, I have made zsh the default by `chsh -s $(which zsh)`, but when using Run/Debug Configurations it uses the default non-interactive shell, which is dash as far as I know. And my environment variables and PATH are all set in .zshrc, which is not sourced by dash.

It seems in CLion, it is possible to execute commands in the login shell according to [this YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-27045), but such an option is not available on WebStorm.

Is it possible to use zsh instead of dash as the default non-interactive shell? If not, it would help me a lot to know what is the best practice in such situations.

Comment: _And my environment variables and PATH are all set in .zshrc, which is not sourced by dash._ : I think, this is the least problem. As long as you keep your environment variables in a syntax which is compatible to zsh and dash, you can have them in any file and source this file from a dash startup file and a zsh startup file. Having said this, putting envionment settings into .zshrc is probably not the best idea. If you change an env-variable on the command line and then create a child zsh, the value is replaced by the one in .zshrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73965376/15269030) and the discussion below, I was able to figure it out. (Thank you, @NotTheDr01ds and @lena.)

The main problem is that WebStorm is installed on Windows and therefore knows only the environment variables in Windows. There are two ways to solve the problem as follows.

### Sharing WSL's environment variable to Windows through [`WSLENV`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/)

1. Add the line below to `.zshrc` so that it sets `$WSLENV` when zsh starts.

```bash
export WSLENV=VAR_I_WANT_TO_SHARE:$WSLENV
# Don't forget to insert the colon
# And for some reason, appending the variable after $WSLENV didn't work well
```

2. In Windows, run

```powershell
wsl -e zsh -lic powershell.exe
```

This runs WSL using zsh (logged-in and interactive), then runs powershell which brings you back to Windows. Although this doesn't seem to achieve anything, by going through zsh in WSL, `.zshrc` was sourced and therefore `$WSLENV` set as well. You can check if it worked well by running the below command after you've run the above.

```powershell
$env:VAR_I_WANT_TO_SHARE
```

3. Run WebStorm from the PowerShell that was just created.

```powershell
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.3\bin\webstorm64.exe'
```

When you run or debug any of the Run/Debug Configurations, you will see that the environment variable is shared successfully.

### Setting the PATH in Windows

For most environment variables, the previous method works well. However, PATH is an exception. The Windows PATH is shared to WSL by default. The opposite doesn't work, probably because the PATH in WSL should not interfere with Windows.I've tried adding the `$PATH` of WSL into `$WSLENV` but it didn't seem to work.

In the end, what I did was manually adding each needed `$PATH` of WSL into the Windows PATH.

For example, if there was `export PATH=$PATH:home/(username)/.cargo/bin` in `.zshrc`, you can then add `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\(username)\.cargo\bin` to the Windows `$env:Path` using [the Environment Variable window](https://www.howtogeek.com/787217/how-to-edit-environment-variables-on-windows-10-or-11/).

[image]

---

I might have made some mistakes, so feel free to leave an edit or comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are several questions and points you make:

First, from the question title (and the summary at the end):

> Can I use zsh as the default non-interactive shell for WSL2 Ubuntu?

Well, maybe (using symlinks), but it would be a really bad idea.  So many built-in scripts rely on `/bin/sh` pointing to Dash, or at least Bash.  While Zsh might be compatible with 99.9% of them, eventually there's a strong likelihood that some difference in Zsh would cause a system-level script to fail (or at least produce results inconsistent with those from Dash).

It *is* possible in Ubuntu to change the default non-interactive ("system" shell) from Dash to Bash with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`.  If you select "No" in the resulting dialog, then the system will be updated to point `/bin/sh` to `bash` instead of `dash`.

But not to Zsh, no.

> when using Run/Debug Configurations it uses the default non-interactive shell, which is dash as far as I know

I don't run WebStorm myself, so I'm not sure on this exactly.  Maybe [@lena's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963936/11810933) (or another) will cover it for you, but if it doesn't, I'm noticing [this doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-shell-script.html).  It might be worth trying to specify Zsh in those settings, but again, I can't be sure.

> And my environment variables and PATH are all set in `.zshrc`, which is not sourced by dash.

Hmm.  I'm guessing you would need these set in a `.profile`/`.zprofile` equivalent regardless.  I would assume that WebStorm is executing the shell as a non-interactive one, which means that it wouldn't even parse `~/.bashrc` if Bash was your default shell.

> ... it would help me a lot to know what is the best practice in such situations.

Best practice is probably to make sure that your `~/.profile` has any environment changes needed.  Yes, this violates DRY (don't repeat yourself), but it's probably the best route.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create such a detailed answer. I have learned quite a few new things from this. I tried putting in my environment variable in ~/.profile as you mentioned but the WebStorm Run/Debug Configuration still cannot find that variable. Does .profile get sourced even when it is a non-login & non-interactive shell?

Comment: If WebStorm is installed on Windows and not in WSL, it will read environment neither from `.zshrc` nor from `.profile`, only Windows system environment variables will be inherited

Comment: @lena That's a good point - I was assuming the Linux version of WebStorm here.  But yes, if it is the Windows version, then absolutely, it isn't going to read the environment from WSL (Bash or Zsh or etc.) anyway.  In that case, though, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73451280/11810933) for a possibility using $WSLENV and chain loading WebStorm (the Windows version) through WSL Zsh.  I think that will still work for this particular use-case.

Comment: @S.J.Hoon Good to hear!  `.profile` will be sourced when it is a *login* shell, regardless of whether it is interactive or not.  But also see lena's note -- Are you using the Windows or Linux version of WebStorm in WSL?  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned it in the post. My mistake. As @lena correctly guessed, yes WebStorm is installed on Windows. Thanks for pointing it out. I will take a look at that answer of using WSLENV, thanks.

Comment: I have followed the instructions on you answer and tried executing the following command `wsl -e bash -lic '/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/JetBrains/WebStorm\ 2022.1.3/bin/webstorm64.exe'`, but it just fails without any output. (It didn't seem to be a wrong path problem because when I tried a wrong path intentionally it had an output error.)
Seeing that the command `wsl -e bash -lic 'powershell.exe'` works, it's highly likely an issue with WebStorm

Comment: @S.J.Hoon Bummer.  Not being a WebStorm user, I unfortunately can't test this out and try to come up with a better solution. :-/  I know that the person who asked the other question got it working (in addition to the acceptance, there was a now-cleaned-up comment confirming), but, of course, that's a different executable (albeit from the same company) and a different use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. For now I'll try to focus on making WebStorm run using WSL.

Comment: Oh I just found a workaround by setting WSLENV and `wsl -e bash -lic 'powershell.exe'` like your answer, and executing WebStorm in that same powershell instance. Works like a charm. It's good enough a way for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @S.J.Hoon That's good - You can probably even get the `powershell.exe` to, in turn, execute WebStorm.  I was thinking about the old adage *"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection."* earlier when looking at this  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `npm config set script-shell` command to set the shell for your scripts. Like `npm config set script-shell "/usr/bin/zsh"`.
When `npm run <script name>` spawns a child process, the `SHELL` being used depends on NPM environment. Cм https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script:

> The actual shell your script is run within is platform dependent. By
> default, on Unix-like systems it is the /bin/sh command, on Windows it
> is the cmd.exe. The actual shell referred to by /bin/sh also depends
> on the system. As of npm@5.1.0 you can customize the shell with the
> script-shell configuration

See also https://github.com/npm/npm-lifecycle/blob/10c0c08fc25fea3c18c7c030d4618a401963355a/index.js#L293-L304

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't seem to have any effect sadly. I am currently testing by creating a "test": "echo $SHELL" under package.json and executing that using the Run/Debug Configurations but it still puts out 'bin/sh', and not 'usr/bin/zsh' as I would expect.

Comment: do you use `npm` or `yarn` (`pnpm`, etc.)? the instructions above are for `npm`

Comment: Yes I use `yarn` and did `yarn config set script-shell "/usr/bin/zsh"`, but it seems WebStorm running in Windows might be the reason as you have mentioned. Thanks for asking me just in case though!